# Using docker Selenium node not accessable from my computer

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid, selenium-hub

Using Docker I run Selenium Hub and create two more container and register note.

**This is the logs**

```
07:25:08.215 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2017-12-28 07:25:08.252:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.7.v20170914
2017-12-28 07:25:08.273:INFO:osjs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2017-12-28 07:25:08.273:INFO:osjs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2017-12-28 07:25:08.275:INFO:osjs.session:main: Scavenging every 660000ms
2017-12-28 07:25:08.281:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@23f7d05d{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-12-28 07:25:08.290:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@65d6b83b{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-12-28 07:25:08.290:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1025ms
07:25:08.291 INFO - Nodes should register to http://172.17.0.2:4444/grid/register/
07:25:08.291 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
07:25:15.783 INFO - Registered a node http://172.17.0.3:5555
07:26:08.717 INFO - Registered a node http://172.17.0.4:5555
```

Now I want to run My Test case 
http://172.17.0.3:5555
and http://172.17.0.3:5555

But unfortunately, i am get getting access this two ip,
I am using windows 10,Is there Anyone who can help me to solve this problem

Comment: what are the commands you run up the docker containers with? you need to follow the instructions here https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/hub/ and you will connect to port 4444 on the hub to run your tests - which will pobably be mapped to a different port on your docker host

Comment: i am doing everything as followed